# Using Setters and Getters from a Class

Tags: matlab

I have an class called `TestData` that houses a private property called `data`, which I define as a numeric array. Its goal is to take in data from various other `.m` files and extract the data and place it in the specified format (numeric array. So, a `random_data.m` file that I am currently working with spits out a 1X13 double array called `Avec`. I generate and instance of the class `myTestData = TestData()`; however, because the member variables are private I need to have `getData` and `setData` functions. The only idea I have is to pass `Avec` into `getData` (e.g. `myTestData.getData(Avec)`) and then store it in a temporary array that could then be used by `setData` to write into `data`; but I feel like this is bad practice as that array would need to be public. Also, would it make sense to pass the entire array in or should I pass each element in individually. I would like to have it check the data to make sure that it is in proper format, as well.

I guess in general my concept of how the class works in MATLAB may be flawed.

Thanks for your help in advance and if there is anything else that I can provide, please let me know. Below is some code. The first snippet above the class is from the separate `.m` file.

```
%Write data to file using the TestData Object
Avec = [some 1X13 double array]
myTestData=TestData; % Generate an instance of the object
myTestData.getData(Avec);



classdef TestData
properties (Access = private)
    metaData   % stores meta data in Nx2 array
    data       % stores data in PxQ array
    colLabels  % labels columns
    colUnits   % provides units
    metaPrint  % used to print metaData
    temp       % debugging purposes only
end

methods
    %****************************************************************************%
    %Function: TestData
    %Purpose:  Constructor used to allocate data arrays
    %****************************************************************************%
    function this = TestData() %constructor
        this.metaData   = [];
        this.data       = [];
        this.colLabels  = [];
        this.colUnits   = [];
        this.metaPrint  = [];
        this.temp       = [];
    end %TestData()     

    %%
    %****************************************************************************%
    %Function:
    %Inputs:
    %Purpose:
    %****************************************************************************%        
    function this = getData(this, someArray)
        ????
    end %getData
```

Comment: Some code to be able to reproduce would be useful: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay, I added some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the idea of getters and setters. A get function is designed to take something *from* the object and return it, while a setter is designed to put something *into* a property of the object. You would want something like:

```
function data = getData(this)
  data = this.data;
  % Do any processing to put data into a different format for output
end

function this = setData(this, data)
  % Check the data input to make sure it is the right format, etc.
  this.data = data;
end
```

You may also want to design `setData` to take different types of arguments, like a file name that it can use to load the matrix itself. You could also design your constructor to accept a matrix or file name and initialize `data` as well.

Also, as [Cris alludes to in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976043/using-setters-and-getters-from-a-class#comment92860483_52976911), if the reason you were making `data` private was to control how the user could access and modify it, it's enough to just have getters and setters. You can make `data` public and your [property access methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html) will still be called when accessing the object like `Avec = myTestData.data` or `myTestData.data = Avec`.

Comment: Good answer, but I would add [this reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html). In short, `data` can be public, getters and setters will still be called if they exist.

Comment: @gnovice You were right about my understanding of getters and setters being off. Thank you for clearing that up. As for the `setData` function and its arguments, I do have a function called `writeDataToFile` that I will call once the data is arranged properly; but my idea was to just store it in the array `data` and then write it directly. I would not, in this case, need to apply arguments, correct? Because the `writeDataToFile` function has access to the member variables.

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: Yes, it sounds like your `writeDataToFile` method would only have the object as input, as in `function writeDataToFile(this)`. You would then just call it with `myTestData.writeDataToFile()`.

Comment: @gnovice Another issue I have encountered is when I try to write to the data array in more than one column (my data is formatted as NX1). So, after I write in Avec, I then have 6 more data columns to write. Now, when I call `myTestData.data = Bvec` it, as you would assume, writes over `Avec`. My instinct was to use a `for` loop, but this seems overkill. Also, I would need to do this outside of the object. My thought was to create a temporary array that could take the data in, sort it, and then place it in the `data` array. What would you suggest? Thanks, again!

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: You will likely need to process your data outside your object, concatenate the results (`mat = [Avec Bvec ...];`), then place that in your object (`myTestData.data = mat;`).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I read through your reference and from what I understand your point is that if the properties are public (e.g. data), then when I call `myTestData.data` outside of the object it will still execute the getters and setters that I have written. This makes sense: first, to even call `myTestData.data` , `data` would need to be public; second, I am setting the data = getter. My point of confusion, though, is that the client could still access those member variables and change them, correct? I thought that this was discouraged in oo programming, which is why I wanted to make them private.

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: If you define a setter method for a property, then that setter method will always be called. The only difference with this style of getter/setter is that your user doesn't do `obj.setData(newdata)`, but `obj.data = newdata`. Everything else is the same. So you are still protecting your data from being changed if you want. Note that the getter and setter are called also when accessing the property from class methods, as described in the document I linked.

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: Another dirty trick you can do in MATLAB is define a method `subsasgn`, which is called whenever you do `obj.data = newdata` from outside the class (thus not from class methods). This function can then prevent users from changing the `data` property, even if it is public! The `subsasgn` function makes setters unnecessary. `subsref` is the same for getters.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I must still be confused because I wrote the code like @gnovice described, but if I put a display statement inside the setter it never shows up, implying to me that it is not being called. So, I am still just setting the arrays using `myTestData.data = data`. So I tried another implementation that I found online: `this = set.data(this, data) and it will display the comment; however, it does so twice. Also, when you say I can protect data from being changed if I "want," what specifically is it that I am doing that allows me to achieve that "wanting"? (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: Yes, you need to implement then like in the docs, then they will be called with the `obj.data` syntax. You cannot expect a method with an arbitrary name to be called automatically. I don’t know why your function is called twice now. Feel free to write up a new question for that. I would need to see the full code to know.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I figured it out. It is being called once when I set the data property, but also once when I generate the the instance of the object.

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: Ah! that makes sense. You can initialize your properties where you declare them (in the `properties` section, rather than the constructor). That could be useful for the properties that don't depend on any parameters of the constructor.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I posted another question in relation to this that you would probably know the answer to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016331/getters-and-setters-within-an-object