# Getters and Setters Within an Object

Tags: matlab

I have an object called TestData() that handles data processing and places it in a file in a specified format. One of the properties is `data`, which is stored as an array of type double. Here is the object and its constructor:

```
classdef TestData
properties
    metaData  = [];  % stores meta data in Nx2 array
    data      = [];  % stores data in PxQ array
    colLabels = [];  % labels columns
    colUnits  = [];  % provides units
    metaPrint % used to print metaData
    temp      % debugging purposes only
end

methods
    %****************************************************************************%
    %Function: TestData
    %Purpose:  Constructor used to allocate data arrays
    %****************************************************************************%
    function this = TestData() %constructor
        this.metaPrint  = [];
        this.temp       = [];
    end %TestData()
```

The data that is placed into the object comes from a `.m` file external to the object, like so:

```
myTestData=TestData; % Generate an instance of the object

% Data
ErrorLine1 = zeros([length(ErrorLine')+2 1]); % Empty Vector to store 11X1 
ErrorLine data
ErrorLine1(2:end-1) = ErrorLine(1:end);
mat = [Avec' Bvec' Invec' Ovec' ErrorLine1 PercentErrorOD'];
myTestData.data = mat;
```

So, when I set `myTestData.data = mat` this places the data in the object, but then calls the getter and setter functions for that object. One of the principle reasons for using these functions is to filter the data and determine if it is the correct type of data (in this case, the format would need to be `double`). When I try this in the code, however, it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have written for the getter:

```
    function data = get.data(this)
        data = this.data;
    end %getData
```

And the setter:

```
    function this = set.data(this, data)
        i = arrayfun(@(n)strcmp(class(this.data(n)), 'doube'), 1:numel(this.data)); %#ok<STISA>
        disp(i)
        if any(i == 0)
            disp("WE HAVE A ZERO")
            msg = "Data in object's 'data' property is not of type double";
            error(msg);

        else
            this.data = data;
            disp('Hi from setter')
        end
    end % set.data
```

If I run the `strcmp` and `any` functionality through the command window it works! When I run it from the editor, though, it always displays the "Hi from setter" string, even if I change "double" in the compare to "string." So, I am just not sure why it is not entering the `if` statement.

If there is anything that you can see in my code that could be modified to make it more efficient please let me know. Also, if there is anything else I can do my best. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setter, you have this line:

```
i = arrayfun(@(n)strcmp(class(this.data(n)), 'doube'), 1:numel(this.data));
```

But note that here you have not yet done `this.data = data`. When you test `this.data`, you test the old value of the property, not the value you want to assign. You need to test `data`.

Instead of using `strcmp` on the result of `class`, you can better test with [`isa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html). Furthermore, unless `data` is a cell array or a struct array, each of the elements will always be of the same class. You don't need to iterate over the whole array to test its type, just look at the type of the array itself. In the case of the cell array and the struct array, the indexing has to be different to extract elements. So, `data(n)` will always have the same type as `data`. Thus your setter can be written as:

```
function this = set.data(this, data)
   if ~isa(data,'double')
      error('WRONG!')
   end
   this.data = data;
end
```

---

Another issue with the code: `if any(i == 0)`. `any` collapses one dimension of the input array. So if `i` is a 2D matrix, then the output is a row vector. Each element will be true if any of the elements in the given column is true. The `if` statement is only true if all elements of the given expression are nonzero. That means that all columns must have at least one 0 value for this expression to trigger.

Instead, do `if any(i(:)==0)`. Here we make `i` into a column vector (this doesn't copy data, it's efficient), and thus `any` will return a single (scalar) value. If you have MATLAB R2018b, then you also do `if any(i,'all')`, which is equivalent.

You'll often see code doing `if any(any(i==0))`, but this fails if `i` happens to have three or more dimensions. It is also inefficient, the forms above are better.

Comment: I have another question that I have posted. You have been helpful in the past and I am curious if you could help me out again. It is a fairly complex problem (I think) and you might be the only person willing to answer. Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600805/for-loop-iteration-through-txt-files