# For loop iteration through .txt files

Tags: matlab

I have a function that is part of an object that I have name `TestData`. Here are the properties and its constructor:

```
classdef TestData
properties
    metaData  = [];  % stores meta data in Nx2 array
    data      = [];  % stores data in PxQ array
    colLabels = [];  % labels columns
    colUnits  = [];  % provides units
    temp      = [];  % temporary to bypass setters while structuring data
end

methods
    %% Constructor

    function this = TestData(varargin) % Will take in a variable number of inputs
        if (nargin == 0)
            return;
        end
        if (nargin == 1 && ischar(varargin{1})) % Case of the input being a file (.txt, .s*p, etc..)
            this = readDataFromFile(this, varargin{1});
            return;

        elseif (nargin == 4) % Case of the input being raw data. Note that the order matters. 
            this.metaData  = varargin{1};
            this.colLabels = varargin{2};
            this.colUnits  = varargin{3};
            this.data      = varargin{4};
            return

        else
            error('Not enough input arguments.');
        end       
   end
```

Now, let us say that I have 42 text files that I want to pass into the object. I have created a function for this called `extractData` that sifts through the data and finds a user input x-axis and y-axis. It does so by first calling a function `readDataFromFile`, which sets the property arrays that are outlined in the code above. It is a fairly long function and I won't include it for the time being, but I will say that I do know it is working.

The problem: I make an object of the class called `myTestData` and perform this operation in the CW, `myTestData=myTestData.extractData('Tip Type','Tip S/N')`. This will look for the `Tip Type` and `Tip S/N`. As you can see in the code, the type and S/N are in column 3 of the matrix. If the string is found, it takes the row it was found on, accesses column 3 of that row, and places that value into the `temp` array. In my case, the type is `passive` and the S/N is `AM66191`. It will write this to the temp array, but then on the second iteration of the `for` loop it will write something else over the first row and the `passive` and `AM66191` will be displayed on the second row. It will do this all the way until the end, where on row 42 I will see the type and S/N, but all the other rows are just garbage. I have attached an image of what the temp array looks like after the second iteration of the `for` loop. Here is the code for the `extractData` function:

```
        function this = extractData(this, xAxis, yAxis)
        s = dir('*.txt'); % Gather all text files
        disp(length(s))
        for i=1:length(s) % Loop through and gather data until last element of strcuct
            j = 1;
            fid = s(i).name; % Open file in read-only mode
            this = this.readDataFromFile(fid);
            disp(fid)
            x = this.metaData(find(contains(this.metaData(:,1), xAxis)),3);
            this.temp(i,j) = x;
            disp(this.temp(i,j))
            j = j+1;
            y = this.metaData(find(contains(this.metaData, yAxis)),3); %#ok<*FNDSB>
            this.temp(i,j) = y;
            disp(this.temp(i,j))
        end %for            
    end %extractData
```

[image: After 2nd iteration of for loop]

Comment: Does `this = this.readDataFromFile(fid);` overwrite the `temp` field?

Comment: I was wondering this! But how do I call the function otherwise?

Comment: Ahhh, I got it to work. It was something funky with the temp array